# JDABuilder is not recognized by Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to build a discord bot, and to do so, I had to add a reference library called JDA. I did this, and added in the proper files (source files) needed by the library, however Eclipse does not seem to recognize JDABuilder from the library. I've tried reinstalling the library, nothing changed,  using an older version of the library, which caused more errors of the same type for other things used. The error I get is

> The import net.dv8tion.jda.core.JDABuilder cannot be resolved

and

> JDABuilder cannot be resolved to a type (On the new JDA line)

Not really sure how to fix this. Any help would be much appreciated!!

```
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.AccountType;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.JDA;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.JDABuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.exceptions.RateLimitedException;
import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;

public class Connecting {

public static void main (String[] args) {   

JDA discord = null;

discord = new JDABuilder(AccountType.BOT).setToken(Token.discordToken).buildBlocking();`

    }
}
```

Comment: did you add via project, properties, java build path, libraries?

Comment: Yes I did, and then I clicked add External JAR, and selected the JDA file (Got the one with dependancies included.. I also put in the javadoc.jar and sources.jar files in the appropriate places.

Comment: in your package explorer, can you browse the jda under referenced libraries? or doesn't it show up there

Comment: I am able to get to it under Referenced Libraries in Packaged Explorer.

Comment: is your project set to build automatically? Your project might need a rebuild to update dependencies. project > build automatically

Comment: Yep, already set to automatically build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who tried helping me, I fixed the issue by following [this tutorial here, gradle set up included.](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/2%29-Eclipse-Setup)

I basically switched to Eclipse for Java Developers for my IDE,  changed my reference jre  library from jre to JavaSE 1.7, then made a new Gradle project and put a build.gradle file in there with the code for the particular type of program I am trying to make here.